# iOS 11 AutoFill password feature doesn't work with other language than English language

Tags: swift, ios11

I have iOS app using Swift language that uses [the new Autofill password feature in iOS 11](https://medium.com/anilvarghese/ios-11-password-autofill-e1c763015bc1).

I am using  `textField.textContentType` with username and password fields.

Everything works fine when the language of iPhone remains English.
Problem is that the AutoFill key icon option does not appear on the keyboard when the iPhone language is other than English (for example Finnish-Finland language).

Comment: I just sent Apple bug report for iOS 11.

Comment: Just noticed this after spending 2 hours debugging why the password fill WOULD just not appear.

Comment: Another combinations not working: Czech language with Czech keyboard; UK English language with US English keyboard (but it works with UK English keyboard in such case); I really do not get the reason for this.

Answer (score 0):

It won't work on 11, but this is fixed in iOS 12 (beta).

I've tested it with a dutch language keyboard, and the suggestion/password button is shown correctly.